# Used dd to copy liveusb partition to internal macbook drive. After reboot all I see is a grey screen

Tags: boot, macbook

I was trying to boot a macbook using a  liveusb, but it didn't work because my macbook model can't boot from usb. I created a new internal partition and tried to dd the liveusb onto it.

After I rebooted, the screen stays grey.

I suspect the partition I dd'ed to might have been smaller than the one I copied from, can this have corrupted the hard drive?

I tried a number of different key combination at startup, including

- `command+r` - recovery mode
- `c` - boot from cd
- `t` - target mode, not sure what it's supposed to do, but doesn't work
- `command+option+r+p` - reset nvram

The only thing that seemed to have any effect at all was resetting the nvram, but it didn't solve the issue. For all the other combinations, all I see is a grey screen and nothing else.

I tried disconnecting the internal drive, but it didn't help. Does macbooks require a valid internal drive to boot off a cd?

It's a macbook from mid 2010 and its version is 7,1. I have rEFIt and bootcamp installed.

Answer (score 0):

Today, I tried one more to disconnect the drive and boot off a cd. This time it worked.

It turned out that a partition on the disk was indeed causing the bootloader to crash.

What I did in the end, was to disconnect the drive, then hold `option` to get the boot selection menu, then reconnected the drive while the machine was running and booted off a linux mint live dvd. I deleted the partition i tried to `dd` to, rebooted and everything was working again.

TL;DR If you have a similar problem try disconnecting the hd and boot off a cd (not a usb stick as that won't work).